# Django Url Parameters Wont Function Correctly

Tags: django, django-urls

I am having trouble trying to get url text into one of my views.

Url Conf

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^quizaddquestion/$', 'quiz.views.quizaddquestion'),
    (r'^quizaddquestion/(?P<quizname>\w+)/$', 'quiz.views.quizaddquestion'),
)
```

View Code

```
def quizaddquestion(request,quizname=None):
    print "this is the quizname : %s" %quizname
    #view code here...
```

My view code without that kwarg works perfectly, but the quizname kwarg doesn't work.
The above code returns:

```
this is the quizname : None
```

For some reason, it's not getting from the url to the view. Everything else works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the URL you were using to test?

Comment: localhost:8000/quizaddquestion/this. this never gets to the view

Comment: try `localhost:8000/quizaddquestion/this/` with the `/` at the end

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't work. I've even created a new virtualenv to see if it was some kind of bug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inverting the order of the URLs?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^quizaddquestion/(?P<quizname>\w+)/$', 'quiz.views.quizaddquestion'),
    (r'^quizaddquestion/$', 'quiz.views.quizaddquestion'),
)
```